# Load PDF from assets folder in android

Tags: android

I have a pdf in my assets folder. I want to load in my activity using a webview. Is it possible. or is there anyother way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

u can do onething 
create a folder named "raw" in "res" then put ur file there
in code write this

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filename)
```

Comment: for that u have to download some api or built ur own Pdf viewer

Answer (score 0):

To get the asset, you will want to use the [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) to load the file.

The problem will be rendering the PDF file, unless your WebView is able to render the file you will end up with jumpled garbage. You can also access it from Resources, but again, WebView doesn't know how to render PDFs.

[Old Mailing list about this](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg38021.html)

> openRawResource(int id, TypedValue
>   value) Open a data stream for reading
>   a raw resource.

-- edit --

So if you just wanted the WebView to prompt the user to "download" the PDF file from the application, then you want to do something like what WebViewDemo does:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/demo.html");
```

or it might make more sense to use the [setDownloadListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setDownloadListener%28android.webkit.DownloadListener%29) or going through [loadDataWithBaseUrl](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) methods

Comment: I am using this code, but only a white screen of webview is coming                WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);        
           webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
           webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/guide.pdf");

Comment: does the DDMS logs show anything? WebKit should be complaining about that